# Castle Windsor 3.0 Breaking Changes

Tags: castle-windsor, castle

In the spirit of this question: [Castle Windsor 2.5 Breaking Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647595/castle-windsor-2-5-breaking-changes)

Is there a comprehensive list of why my code is broken now and how I go about fixing it?  My  googlefu is failing me.

Comment: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/BreakingChanges.txt

Comment: @MauricioScheffer this should be an answer, not a comment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Mauricio Sheffer wrote in his comment, there's a `breakingchanges.txt` file that does just that.

It is included in the package you downloaded and also available online [here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/BreakingChanges.txt).

Comment: That's it.  For some reason, the Google couldn't find it.  Now that it is a Stack question, the Google shall find it for ever and ever.